# Using for loop in a data frame

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, pandas, append

I have two separate data frames, one of which lists years, starting from 1900 to 2012. The other data frame has 8 different flow measuring gauging stations with flow data.

I want to extract the annual maximum flow data for each gauging station, and populate that into a single data frame.

How can this be done?

Comment: i am able to extract the maximum annual flow values but not able to put them into a single data frame...

Comment: It would be good if you show some of what you have tried and an example table so people can help more effectively

Comment: I have edited your question to hopefully make it a bit more readable. Still, you should add the code you have tried with. For instance, in the title your mention a for-loop. Please add that for-loop code in your question and point out which part of it you have an issue with.